# Is it possible to grow a rose from a cut stem in a bouquet?

Tags: roses

My dying rose bouquet is growing new leaves. I cut the dead flowers and placed the stem in water with some root hormone in a well lit area. Does anyone think I'll have any success?

Comment: @Stephie I think this adds an extra detail, including what Rosemary has done to prepare her flowers.

Comment: Welcome to the site Rosemary! It's so nice of you to take the advice given you to ask a new question. This place isn't easy for beginners, and we need more people like you. I see you've already taken our [tour] and visited our [help], but if you have any questions about how we do things, just leave us a note. Thanks for hanging in, we look forward to getting to know you better!

Comment: Thank you so much Stephie, thanks for the warm welcome Sue.. Looking forward to be a good gardener